# Can't get hibernate to work in Spring web flow project

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-webflow, hibernate-search

I am trying to use hibernate in a Spring Web Flow Porject but I am getting the following error. I been looking at this and dont know why I am getting the error

Here is my database.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"

       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd">



  <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:jdbc.properties" />

  <context:component-scan base-package="org.uftwf" />

  <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager"/>

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}" />
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${database.user}" />
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
        <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="300000" />
        <property name="numTestsPerEvictionRun" value="6" />
        <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="1800000" />
        <property name="initialSize" value="3" />
        <property name="maxActive" value="10" />
        <property name="maxIdle" value="10" />
        <property name="maxWait" value="5000" />
        <property name="poolPreparedStatements" value="true" />
       <property name="maxOpenPreparedStatements" value="100" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>org.uftwf.schoolvisit.model.VisitModel</value>
            </list>
        </property>

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>             
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="hibernateTransactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Here is my error: can someone please tell me why

```
2012-08-28 13:20:08,222 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'database': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory org.uftwf.schoolvisit.database.DatabaseImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/database.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:385)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:284)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:618)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1582)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

Here is my files:

```
activation-1.1.jar
antlr-2.7.6.jar
aopalliance-1.0.jar
asm-3.1.jar
asm-attrs-1.5.3.jar
aspectjrt-1.6.8.jar
aspectjweaver-1.6.8.jar
cas-client-core-3.2.1.jar
cglib-2.2.jar
commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar
commons-codec-1.4.jar
commons-collections-3.1.jar
commons-dbcp.jar
commons-digester-1.8.1.jar
commons-email-1.0.jar
commons-fileupload-1.1.1.jar
commons-io-1.1.jar
commons-lang-2.5.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
commons-pool.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
dumbster-1.6.jar
ehcache-1.2.3.jar
files.txt
hibernate-3.2.6.ga.jar
hibernate-annotations-3.5.0-Final.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-3.2.0.Final.jar
hibernate-core-3.5.0-Final.jar
hibernate-entitymanager-3.5.0-Final.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
hibernate-search-3.0.0.GA.jar
hibernate-validator-4.0.2.GA.jar
hsqldb-1.8.0.10.jar
httpclient-4.1.2.jar
httpclient-cache-4.1.2.jar
httpcore-4.1.2.jar
httpmime-4.1.2.jar
icu4j-2.6.1.jar
jackson-core-asl-1.5.3.jar
jackson-mapper-asl-1.5.3.jar
javassist-3.9.0.GA.jar
jaxb-api-2.1.jar
jaxb-impl-2.1.3.jar
jaxen-1.1.1.jar
jcl-over-slf4j-1.5.10.jar
jdom-1.0.jar
joda-time-1.6.jar
joda-time-jsptags-1.0.2.jar
jstl-1.2.jar
jta-1.1.jar
list.txt
log4j-1.2.15.jar
lucene-core-2.3.2.jar
lucene-highlighter-2.0.0.jar
mail-1.4.jar
mysql-connector-java-5.0.5.jar
org.springframework.aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.asm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.aspects-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.binding-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.context.support-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.core-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.expression-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.faces-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.instrument-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.instrument.tomcat-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.jdbc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.jms-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.js-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.js.resources-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.orm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.oxm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.test-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.transaction-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.webflow-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.web.portlet-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.web.servlet-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.web.struts-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
persistence-api-1.0.jar
quartz-1.5.2.jar
slf4j-api-1.5.10.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.5.10.jar
spring-security-cas-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-config-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-config-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-core-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-crypto-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-ldap-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-openid-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-remoting-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-taglibs-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-tx-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
stax-api-1.0-2.jar
tiles-api-2.1.3.jar
tiles-core-2.1.3.jar
tiles-jsp-2.1.3.jar
tiles-servlet-2.1.3.jar
urlrewritefilter-3.1.0.jar
validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar
xalan-2.6.0.jar
xml-apis-1.3.02.jar
xmlParserAPIs-2.6.2.jar
xom-1.0.jar
```

Comment: What version of Hibernate are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you may have more than one version of Spring on your classpath. See here for more information on IncompatibleClassChangeError:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/binaryComp.html